Helm must override values yaml file
I have structure similar to the following example:
values.yaml
config:
  value: "unset"

values-dev.yaml
config:
  value: "development"

values-prod.yaml
config:
  value: "production"

I need to make sure that the value is set by the specific environment and, if we forget to add it to the values-*env*.yaml, the templating step should fail.
In other words, in the example above there should NEVER be "unset" in any enviornment and if we create a new values-**.yaml file with no value: "something" inside, it should fail during templating.
I couldn't find a way to do it in the documentation

The most straightforward path to this is to use Helm's required template function.
In your chart's values.yaml, do not provide a value for the required-with-no-default setting.  It may be helpful to include the containing value explicitly as a YAML mapping.
# values.yaml
config: {}
  # value: not mentioned here

At the point where you go to use the value, include required in a pipeline.  That will fail if the value isn't present (more specifically if it's nil or another "falsey" value).
# templates/deployment.yaml
env
- name: ENVIRONMENT
  value: {{ .Values.config.value | required "config.value setting is required" }}

(You need more complex logic if it's possible the config wrapper doesn't exist either.  You need different logic if "falsey" values like zero or empty-string are legitimate values, probably containing the Sprig hasKey function with Helm fail and conditionals as shown in @RuiJarimba's answer.)

[ERROR] values.yaml: unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.config.value | required "Invalid value" .Values.config.value":interface {}(nil)}
[ERROR] templates/: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.config.value | required "Invalid value" .Values.config.value":interface {}(nil)}
I believe that this is because the generic "values.yaml" file is analysed before the specific "values-env.yaml" file and there is no "value" yet

Are you trying to put the required invocation in your values.yaml file?  It needs to go in a templates/*.yaml file, at the point where you use the value.  The field shouldn't be mentioned in values.yaml at all.

@DavidMaze is right. If you're trying to use the required keyword in your values.yaml files, it will not work as the values.yaml itself cannot be templated via Helm. If that is something you're trying to achieve, you might have a look at Helmfile.

Thank you for the suggestion, that was my issue. Now I'm putting it in the template/*.yaml files and it is working properly!

You can use Flow control (if/else) and fail function to validate the parameters.
Consider the following example:
config-map.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  my-data-key: {{- if regexMatch "^(development|production)$" .Values.config.value }}
    {{- .Values.config.value | indent 1 }}
  {{- else }}
    {{- fail "Invalid value for config.value parameter. Valid values are 'development' and 'production'." }}
  {{- end }}

values.yaml
config:
  value: "unset"

values-dev.yaml
config:
  value: "development"

values-prod.yaml
config:
  value: "production"

Output of helm template with the default value (config.value=unset), which is invalid throws an error:
Error: execution error at (example-01/templates/configmap.yaml:9:8): Invalid value for config.value parameter. Valid values are 'development' and 'production'.

Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML

Output of helm template . -f values-prod.yaml (valid value):
---
# Source: example-01/templates/config-map.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  my-data-key: production

